# Разные блоки в разные строки?

Tags: css

Я имею такую разметку и изменить ее не могу:

```html
<ul class="products columns-4">
   <li class="product-category product first">  </li>
   <li class="product-category product"> </li>

   <li class="product type-product"> </li>
   <li class="product type-product"> </li>
   <li class="product type-product"> </li>
   <li class="product type-product"> </li>
</ul>
```

Все блоки идут один за другим (т.е в ряд). Блоков `product-category` и  `product type-product`  может быть разное кол-во.

Как сделать, чтобы блоки с классом `product type-product` начинались с новой строки?

Comment: А сейчас они с какой строки начинаются, со старой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот вам решение на CSS.

Красным цветом выделен первый элемент с классом `product type-product`, с которого и начинается новая строка. Ваша задача решена.

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: chocolate;
}

.products>.product-category+ :not(.product-category) {
  clear: both;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="products columns-4">
  <li class="product-category product first"> 1</li>
  <li class="product-category product">2 </li>

  <li class="product type-product"> 3</li>
  <li class="product type-product"> 4</li>
  <li class="product type-product"> 5</li>
  <li class="product type-product"> 6</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.products > li {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;  
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
 }
 .products > li.product.type-product {
  clear: left
 }
```

```html
<ul class="products columns-4">
   <li class="product-category product first"></li>
   <li class="product-category product"></li>

   <li class="product type-product"></li>
   <li class="product type-product"></li>
   <li class="product type-product"></li>
   <li class="product type-product"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: . ну почти, только блоки должны быть в ряд

Comment: @Oiki Первые два блока идут в ряд, остальные переходят на следующий, так как у них есть класс product type-product. Разве не такие ваши условия были?